# How to build one efficient alpha numbering?

Tags: numbering

Seeing [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37447/a-new-kind-of-symbol-wrapping), I'm looking for one good solution for alpha numbering. For my point of view, the way the numbering must be displayed depends on the maximum of the numbers.

1. If MAX = 26, then the alpha numbering must be `a, b, c, ..., z`.
2. If MAX = 26^2, then the alpha numbering must be `aa, ab, ac, ..., az, ba, bb, bc, ..., bz, ..., za, zb, zc, ..., zz`.
3. If MAX = 26^n, then the alpha numbering must be similar but with n letters instead of two.

How this features can be obtained by using one command with one constant to indicate the numbers n of letters to use for the alpha numbering ?

Comment: I assume that you specify `MAX` (or `n`) before the counter is used, or should this numbering style automagically figure out how many letters to use?

Comment: If I have to give `MAX` when I call the "alpha-numbering" command, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand {\alphanumbering} { O{3} m } {
    \exp_last_unbraced:Nf \use_none:n {
        \int_to_alph:n {
            \exp_args:Nf \int_from_alph:n { \prg_replicate:nn {#1} {z} }
            + #2 } } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  \alphanumbering{1}, \alphanumbering{2}, \ldots{}, \alphanumbering{26},
  \alphanumbering{27}, \ldots{}, \alphanumbering{2*26},
  \ldots{}, \alphanumbering{26*26}, \ldots{}, \alphanumbering{26*26*26},
  \alphanumbering{26*26*26+1}.

  \alphanumbering[6]{12345}
\end{document}
```