# Error: Counter too large! with \alph{cntr} and cntr>26

Tags: errors, numbering, counters

I would like to have `\alph{counter}` for values larger than 26. The following MnWE gives me the error `! LaTeX Error: Counter too large.`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\def\theenumi{\alph{enumi}}
\setcounter{enumi}{24}
\item twenty-five
\item twenty-six
\item twenty-seven
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I would like it to behave like one of these:

```
..., x, y, z, aa, bb, cc, ..., xx, yy, zz, aaa, bbb, ccc, ... (preferred)
..., x, y, z, aa, ab, ac, ..., ax, ay, az, ba,  bb,  bc,  ... (can be if nothing else works)
```

A solution *without* LaTeX3 extensions would be awesome as I cannot run LaTeX3 extensions.

Comment: Look at the `alphalph` package.

Comment: @egreg Great! Would you like to extend it into an answer or should I post the answer as CW?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The [`alphalph`](http://ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) package by H. Oberdiek provides the second numbering system out of the box. As usual with Heiko's packages, a counter representation such as

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\alphalph{\value{section}}}
```

is completely expandable.

And, as you remark in comments, with

```
\makeatletter
\newalphalph{\alphmult}[mult]{\@alph}{26}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\alphmult{\value{section}}}
```

you get your preferred way. Of course, replace `section` with the counter you need.

Comment: For new kinds of symbol wrapping, see this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37447/a-new-kind-of-symbol-wrapping

Comment: There is a way in the package you mention, it is `\newalphalph{\@aalph}[mult]{\@alph}{26}` `\def\aalph#1{\@aalph{\value{#1}}}` ;)

Comment: @egreg How do you get this to work with `enumitem` package. I do not want to create a question because I have seen another one and it has been closed due to the same reason.

Comment: @azetina I don't think this fits in the `\AddEnumerateCounter` scheme of `enumitem`.

Answer (score 6):

Should you happen to use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) for your bibliography, you may use its `\mknumalph` macro for counter values up to 702 ("zz").

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

% Everything from here to \begin{document} only serves to avoid biber errors
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\def\theenumi{\mknumalph{\value{enumi}}}
\setcounter{enumi}{24}
\item twenty-five
\item twenty-six
\item twenty-seven
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you mention "biber errors"? You don't need to run biber ;-)

Comment: Tell that latexmk. ;-)

Comment: Use [arara](http://cereda.github.com/arara/) ;-)