# Counter too large if number of alphabet chapters is more that 26

Tags: errors, numbering, counters, appendices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error: Counter too large! with \alph{cntr} and cntr>26](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52599/error-counter-too-large-with-alphcntr-and-cntr26)

I need Alphabetic numeration of my chapters.

But if they are more than 26 LaTeX gives an error message.

How I can teach LaTeX to continue numbering as AA, AB, AC etc.?

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\appendix

\setcounter{chapter}{26}

\chapter{foo}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

*LaTeX Error: Counter too large.*

Comment: have you already seen [Error: Counter too large! with \alph{cntr} and cntr>26](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52599/18674)? Maybe it will provide the solution for you.