# Numbering exceeding the 26 letter alphabet

Tags: enumerate, counters, enumitem

After reading this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52604/10898 I am unable to employ the `alphalph` package to replace the counter in either levels. See the code below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{alphalph} % unable to use this package based on the answer given.
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\alph*)}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \item
    \item 
    \item 
    \item 
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I have made the proper replacement but get no results:

```
\makeatletter
\newalphalph{\alphmult}[mult]{\@alph}{26}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\alphmult{\value{enumi}}}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I answered the same question [here](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=17332). The documentation of `enumitem` has an extra section about counters. It's section *8.1 New counter representation*

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\def\enumalphalphcnt#1{\expandafter\@enumalphalphcnt\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@enumalphalphcnt#1{\alphalph{#1}}
\makeatother
\AddEnumerateCounter{\enumalphalphcnt}{\@enumalphalphcnt}{aa}
\setenumerate{label=\arabic*}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\enumalphalphcnt*)}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo
\item bar
\item next level
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo \item bar \item foo
\item bar \item foo \item bar
\item foo \item bar \item foo
\item bar \item foo \item bar
\item foo \item bar \item foo
\item bar \item foo \item bar
\item foo \item bar \item foo
\item bar \item foo \item bar
\item foo \item bar \item foo
\item bar \item foo \item bar
\item foo \item bar \item foo
\item bar \item foo \item bar
\item foo \item bar \item foo
\item bar \item foo \item bar
\item foo \item bar \item foo
\item bar \item foo \item bar
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```