# Changing the item numbering

Tags: enumerate, counters, enumitem

Similar to [Numbering exceeding the 26 letter alphabet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103496/numbering-exceeding-the-26-letter-alphabet) I tried to define Roman numbering. The result is OK, but LaTeX gives me a `Missing number, treated as zero.`-error. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{romanbar}

\makeatletter
\def\enumRomanbarcnt#1{\expandafter\@enumRomanbarcnt\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@enumRomanbarcnt#1{\Romanbar{#1}}
\makeatother

\AddEnumerateCounter{\enumRomanbarcnt}{\@enumRomanbarcnt}{\Romanbar{5}}

\newlist{rnl}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[rnl,1]{label=\arabic*.}

\begin{document}
\begin{rnl}[label={\enumRomanbarcnt*.}]
  \item Text
  \item Text
\end{rnl}
\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be connected to `\Romanbar` (line 7) to never get any parameter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\Romanbar` wants to see an explicit decimal number in its argument, not a counter's name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{romanbar}

\makeatletter
\def\enumRomanbarcnt#1{\expandafter\@enumRomanbarcnt\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@enumRomanbarcnt#1{\expandafter\Romanbar\expandafter{\the#1}}
% also the following line must go before \makeatother
\AddEnumerateCounter{\enumRomanbarcnt}{\@enumRomanbarcnt}{\Romanbar{18}}
\makeatother

\newlist{rnl}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[rnl,1]{label=\enumRomanbarcnt*.}

\begin{document}

\begin{rnl}
  \item Text
  \item Text
\end{rnl}
\end{document}
```

I'd use 18 as the widest number or maybe 48 if you plan to go beyond 30.

Comment: Slap on my forehead! Sure, thanks! The `\makeatother` was misplaced when using copy & paste and in the real text the width of each item "number" is determined and the maximum of it saved via the aux file and then used in the next compilation run. There is also more than 1 level, but all that would not have been minimal. But thanks for pointing this out (maybe somebody reuses the code, after all).