# appendix counter is too large

Tags: fancyhdr

After including more on my appendix, I got the following error: LaTeX Error: Counter to large.

I've got more than 30 sides in the appendix, but after Z the acrobat shows AA, BB, ... that's ok, but these pagenumbers aren't shown like the A, B, C, ... on the page and seem to throw the error.

How can I show the pagenumbers and fix it?

Here's an extract of my document (sorry, my pagestyle is a bit confusing):

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt,english,openright]{report}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[...]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
....
\begin{document}
%define pagestyle
\fancyhf{}  % empty header and footer
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} 
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}%leftmark produce CHAPTER 2. CHAPTER TWO TITLE
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rightmark}%rightmark produce 2.3 SECTION TITLE
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}%empty for NO style, plain for just a page number
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%\chapter causes plain page style. So redefine it for chapter sites
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
 }
 %
....
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{appendices}
\input{./chapters/appendix}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The posted code doesn't help anyone understand the problem, please remove the `...` and `\input`  and jump towards the end with `\setcounter{chapter}{24}` or something then make a small example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I found  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52599/error-counter-too-large-with-alphcntr-and-cntr26 that could help you expand the counter capacity. The solution provided there uses lowercase letters, it should work with uppercase too.

The `alphalph` package should be the way to go

Comment: When using the alphalph package with \appendix
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\AlphAlph{\value{page}}}
It seems that \value{page} return zero ("DivisionByZero ... A number should have been here; I inserted '0'"), if I replace it with '1' there's no error and always an 'A'