# Subequations with more than 26 items

Tags: numbering, subequations

I need any solution to this problem. I have a `subequations` environment with an `align` environment inside of it, and then a bunch of equations. A **lot** of equations. Actually more than 26. When I try to compile it, I only get a `Counter too large` error (I expected something like this).

Is there any way to work around this problem? I am okay with switching from letters to arabic numbers to identify subequations, I am okay with starting with `aa`, `ab` and so on, anything will do.

I am quite a notice to latex so please don't assume anything.

Comment: Related: [Error: Counter too large! with `\alph{cntr}` and cntr>26](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52599/5764)

Answer (score 5):

This is due to the sub-equations being numbers using `\alph`, and there are only 26 choice a, ..., z. You can use the [`alphalph` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) to increase this *enumeration* using a a, ..., z, aa, ..., zz, aaa, ..., style sequence.

The default `subequation` numbering uses `\alph`, which can be patched using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alphalph,etoolbox}

% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\subequations}{\alph{equation}}{\alphalph{\value{equation}}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```