# Subequation: Counter too large

Tags: counters, subequations

I have several parent equations each with more than 30 subequations.
When I write it normally with subequation command, I receive "counter too large" error.

I found out that there is a package named "alphalph" which can solve these numberings with different styles. I have seen [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298406/subequations-with-more-than-26-items?lq=1) for subequations in StackExchange, but it doesn't work for me! I still get the error!! (since I want to refer to them later, I need to label them too).

Does anybody know where the problem is, or suggest an alternative?

Thanks

Comment: Please attach a MWE and the error code.

Comment: can you provide a compilable example?  that will make it much easier for potential helpers to help.

Comment: Thank you guys; one of the solutions worked for me. 
@MaestroGlanz: I don't know what MWE is.

Comment: @PeyM87: `MWE` means minimal working example, i.e. a compilable document that shows the issue or is suited as a starter to add a requested feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, perhaps!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\alphalphval}[1]{\alphalph{\value{#1}}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{subequations}{%
    \let\alph\alphalphval%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c 
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Update with a different style:

In order to get the `aa,bb,cc` style, it's necessary to use `\newalphalph` to define a new style, say, `\aalphalph` (see the code for the precise definition`and let`\alph`use`\aalphalph` then.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\makeatletter
\newalphalph{\aalphalph}[mult]{\alphalph@alph}{26}
\newcommand{\alphalphval}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#1}{% check first if #1 is a counter (\c@#1)
    \aalphalph{#1}% No, it's most likely the direct value
  }{%
    \aalphalph{\value{#1}}% It's a counter, so use \value{#1}
  }
}
\makeatother


\AtBeginEnvironment{subequations}{%
  \let\alph\alphalphval%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c 
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The subequations code is taken from Werner's answer

Comment: Thank you. This one worked. I have upvoted and accepted your answer. Just in case, do you know how I can change the citing style in this answer?

Comment: @PeyM87: Which citing style?

Comment: There's one style: aa, bb, ...;
There's another one like: ab, ac, ... and ....

Comment: @PeyM87: See the update at the end of my answer. Personally, `aa,bb,..` isn't my favourite, however ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Patch `subequations` to use `\alphalph` instead of `\alph`; a similar patch might be used for numbering subequations in a different fashion.

The pictures just show the last rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\subequations}{\alph{equation}}{\alphalph{\value{equation}}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
    f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c 
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can obtain subequations numbered “1-01” and so on with

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\subequations}
  {\alph{equation}}
  {-\two@digits{\arabic{equation}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

instead of the `\patchcmd` line above. In this case loading `alphalph` is not necessary. (I assume you don't have more than 99 subequations.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But as I mentioned, this didn't work for me!