# Label equations with numbers with optidef

Tags: equations, labels, optidef

This might be a dumb question but I am writing my model with `optidef`.

Using such a environment

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage [short]{optidef}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,breaklines=true}
%Title Page
\title{ \\ Something \\ \textnormal{Version -2}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{mini#}|sizeFormat|[constraintFormat]<break>
{optimizationVariable}
{objectiveFunction\label{objective}}
{\label{optimizationProblem}}
{optimizationResult}
\addConstraint{LHS.1}{RHS.1\label{Const1}}{extraConst1}
\addConstraint{LHS.2}{RHS.2\label{Const2}}{extraConst2}
.
.
\addConstraint{LHS.N}{RHS.N\label{ConstN}}{extraConstN}
\end{mini#}
\end{document}
```

Then the equations are labelled as (1a)..(1z)

The problem is that I have many equaltions here that go beyong 26 so I got this kind of error.

```
Latex error: Counter too large
```

My question is how I can change the label into numbers like (1) (2)...so that I can avoid this problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Can you post your `MWE` as in executable format?

Comment: Are there any news here? Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: `optidef` uses the `subequations` environment from  `amsmath` to generate the (1a), (1b), ... listings. This means that the solution to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312456/subequation-counter-too-large) should in principle also be applicable to this case.