# Use two letters for counter

Tags: counters

I use letters to indicate footnotes, so I use the `\alph` command to output the footnote number.

The problem is that `\alph` can only handle numbers up to 26 (corresponding to the letter z). Is there any way to have the count continue with aa, ab, ac, ..., az, ba, bb, ... (or something similar) for the values 27, 28, 29, ...

Comment: package `alphalph`

Comment: [Error: Counter too large! with \alph{cntr} and cntr>26](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52604)

Comment: Perfect, @Johannes_B. If you turn your comment into an answer, I will acknowledge it as the answer to my question. (Or I could just delete the question :-) )

Comment: We can mark it as a duplicate.