# Alphabetical line-numbering for texts which exceed 26 lines with reledmac package

Tags: line-numbering, reledmac, alphabet

I'm using the [reledmac](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/reledmac) package and I'm trying to apply the alphabetical lineation for a text that exceeds the current maximum number of alphabetical characters allowed by the package itself (= 26, as the letters of the english alphabet): this results in an error which says "counter too large".

I would ask if there is a way to solve this problem, maybe using reledmac in combination with the [alphalph](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) package, which seems to work with numbered sections ([Error: Counter too large! with \alph{cntr} and cntr>26](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52599/error-counter-too-large-with-alphcntr-and-cntr26)).

Here is an MWE that shows this problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[noend]{reledmac}
\usepackage[continuousnumberingwithcolumns]{reledpar}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\linenumberstyle*{alph}
\firstlinenum*{1}
\linenumincrement*{1}

\vspace*{1cm}

\beginnumbering
\pstart

\lipsum[1-3]

\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

EDIT: I found that using

```
\usepackage{lineno}
\renewcommand\thelinenumber{\alph{linenumber}}
```

with

```
\renewcommand{\thelinenumber}{\alphalph{\value{linenumber}}}
```

will print the line numbers alphabetical list as intended, as you can see in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{alphalph}

\usepackage{lineno}
\renewcommand\thelinenumber{\alph{linenumber}}

\renewcommand{\thelinenumber}{\alphalph{\value{linenumber}}}

\begin{linenumbers}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{linenumbers}

\end{document}
```

It is possible to use a similar command in combination with reledmac? This is imporant because my focus is to use the feature offered by the reledmac package and not to print a simple line numbers alphabetical list, which package \lineno managed to do well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`linenumber` is a LaTeX counter, not a TeX couter, so that can't be directly tranposed to reledmac.

But you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend,noeledsec]{reledmac}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\linenumincrement{1}
\firstlinenum{1}

\def\linenumrep#1{\alphalph{\the#1}}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur,
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur,
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: To alternate sections with arabic line numbers and sections with alphabetical line numbers it is necessary to add \def\linenumrep#1{\alphalph{\the#1}} just after the \beginnumbering of each sections, and it will give alphabetical line numbers only for that section.

Comment: you should try to do it before the beginnumbering. I think that is cleaner.