# Latex error, counter too large, Subfigures

Tags: subfloats, counters

I'm creating an appendix for a Master thesis and I have lots of pictures that I want to insert. I receive an error message that the counter reaches the letter (z) and I do not know how to solve this. I have far more pictures to insert, but then they cannot be labelled properly.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: What package (or class) provides you with subfloat functionality?

Comment: The suggestion here would be to adjust the counter display using [`alphalph`](http://ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) (if you wish to keep an alphabetic numbering; see [Error: Counter too large! with `\alph{cntr}` and cntr>26](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52599/5764)), or switch to `\arabic`.

Comment: Hi Werner and thanks for helping me. I have used the follwing package: \usepackage{subfig}. I thought of changing to integer countering, but I could not find it and wrote here for help. Will arabic give me integers? Is is simply \usepackage{arabic} ?

Answer (score 9):

Some details on @Werner's comment: if you use, say,  the `subfigure` environment, these lines in your preamble should solve your problem:

```
\usepackage{alphalph}
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{%
\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}%
}%
```

After `z`, you'll get `aa,ab,\dots`. from `subcaption`

If you prefer a numeric subfigure counter, just use something like:

```
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{(\arabic{subfigure})}
```

or  if you want to prefix with the main figure number:

```
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{(\thefigure.\arabic{subfigure})}
```

Comment: Hi Bernard, Thank you for your help! It works fine, but I would prefer to only use integers instead of letters. Do you perhaps have a suggestion of how to do this?

Comment: I've added two other suggestions.

Comment: Werner and Bernard, a huge thank you to both of you! Im quite new with LaTex but now I see the simplicity of the changes in the code. Best regards, Gustaf

Comment: You're very welcome. It's a pleasure to help.